# Rally custom app - getting child element

Tags: rally, ca

I want to create a custom app for Rally to display the test case details. There is a field name 'LastResult' with test case inside which there is a field named 'c_blockedReason'.

How can I display 'c_blockedReason' on the same custom app instead of providing it as a reference.

Code I have written so far,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Grid Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.1/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        Rally.onReady(function() {
            Ext.define('Rally.example.SimpleGrid', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                componentCls: 'app',

                launch: function() {
                    this.add({
                        xtype: 'rallygrid',
                        columnCfgs: [
                            'FormattedID',
                            'Name',
                            'Owner','Method','Type',
                            'LastVerdict',
                            'LastResult',
                        ],
                        context: this.getContext(),
                        enableEditing: false,
                        showRowActionsColumn: false,
                        storeConfig: {
                            model: 'testcase'
                        }
                    });
                }
            });


            Rally.launchApp('Rally.example.SimpleGrid', {
              name: 'Grid Example'
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is a two-parter.  First you need to fetch that c_BlockedReason field by adding a fetch to your storeConfig:

```
storeConfig: {
    model: 'testcase',
    fetch: ['c_BlockedReason']
}
```

Next, you need to add a custom renderer to your set of columnCfgs:

```
{
    text: 'Blocked Reason',
    dataIndex: 'c_BlockedReason',
    renderer: function(value, metaData, record) {
        var verdict = record.get('LastVerdict');
        return (verdict && verdict.c_BlockedReason) || '--';
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not getting. Webpage is displayed blank.

Comment: hmm, it worked in my demo app i was playing with.  can you provide your full source?

Comment: Code that I have provided is my full source